# Controlling 2WD car chassis with PS3 controller

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, motor, shields

I'm having trouble with controlling my car with the PS3 joystick, and there hasn't been any example codes out there. I'm using;

- PS3USB library from USB_Host_shield_2.0 library
- Freetronics H Bridge shield http://www.freetronics.com.au/collections/shields/products/hbridge-dual-channel-h-bridge-motor-driver-shield#.VXMqXUJJmgM

This is my code;

```
include <PS3USB.h>

// Satisfy the IDE, which needs to see the include statment in the ino too.
#ifdef dobogusinclude
#include <spi4teensy3.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#endif

USB Usb;
/* You can create the instance of the class in two ways */
PS3USB PS3(&Usb); // This will just create the instance
//PS3USB PS3(&Usb,0x00,0x15,0x83,0x3D,0x0A,0x57); // This will also store the bluetooth address - this can be obtained from the dongle when running the sketch

bool printAngle;
uint8_t state = 0;

int motora1 = 4;
int motora2 = 7;
int motoraspeed = 6;
int motorb1 = 3;
int motorb2 = 2;
int motorbspeed = 5;


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
#if !defined(__MIPSEL__)
  while (!Serial); // Wait for serial port to connect - used on Leonardo, Teensy and other boards with built-in USB CDC serial connection
#endif
  if (Usb.Init() == -1) {
    Serial.print(F("\r\nOSC did not start"));
    while (1); //halt
  }
  Serial.print(F("\r\nPS3 USB Library Started"));
  pinMode(motora1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motora2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motoraspeed, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(motorb1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorb2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(motorbspeed, OUTPUT);  
  delay(5000); 
}

void loop() {
  Usb.Task();

  if (PS3.PS3Connected || PS3.PS3NavigationConnected) {

    //go forward
     if (PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY) == 0) {
       Serial.print(F("\r\nLeftHatY: "));
      Serial.print(PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY));
         digitalWrite(motora1, HIGH);
          digitalWrite(motora2, LOW);
          digitalWrite(motoraspeed, 255);
        digitalWrite(motorb1, HIGH);
        digitalWrite(motorb2, LOW);
        digitalWrite(motorbspeed, 255);  
}

//go backward
if (PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY) == 255) {
       Serial.print(F("\r\nLeftHatY: "));
      Serial.print(PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY));
           digitalWrite(motora1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motora2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motoraspeed, 255);
  digitalWrite(motorb1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorb2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorbspeed, 255);  
}

//turn left
if (PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatX) == 0) {
       Serial.print(F("\r\RightHatX: "));
      Serial.print(PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatX));
           digitalWrite(motora1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motora2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motoraspeed, 200);
  digitalWrite(motorb1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorb2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorbspeed, 200);   
}

   //turn right
   if (PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatX) == 255) {
       Serial.print(F("\r\RightHatX: "));
      Serial.print(PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatX));
          digitalWrite(motora1, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motora2, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motoraspeed, 200);
  digitalWrite(motorb1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(motorb2, LOW);
  digitalWrite(motorbspeed, 200);   
}
```

As of now, when I look at my code in the serial monitor, I get the following;

```
LeftHatY: 131
RightHatX: 127
LeftHatY: 130
RightHatX: 127
LeftHatY: 130
RightHatX: 127
LeftHatY: 130
RightHatX: 127
LeftHatY: 130
RightHatX: 127
LeftHatY: 131
RightHatX: 127
LeftHatY: 131
RightHatX: 127
LeftHatY: 131
RightHatX: 127
LeftHatY: 131
RightHatX: 127
LeftHatY: 131
RightHatX: 127
LeftHatY: 131
RightHatX: 127
LeftHatY: 131
RightHatX: 127
LeftHatY: 131
RightHatX: 127
LeftHatY: 130
RightHatX: 127
LeftHatY: 130
RightHatX: 127
LeftHatY: 130
RightHatX: 127
LeftHatY: 130
RightHatX: 127
LeftHatY: 131
RightHatX: 127
LeftHatY: 131
RightHatX: 127
LeftHatY: 131
RightHatX: 127
```

The numbers adjust as I'm moving the joystick around but just keeps going even though I'm not moving the joystick around. Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I found three issues:

1. You don't have a `#` before the include on line 1.
2. There is no `}` at the end of the `void loop()`.
3. You forgot to include an if statement for when the joystick is idle.

Try this code:

```
#include <PS3USB.h>

    // Satisfy the IDE, which needs to see the include statment in the ino too.
#ifdef dobogusinclude
#include <spi4teensy3.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#endif

USB Usb;
/* You can create the instance of the class in two ways */
PS3USB PS3(&Usb); // This will just create the instance
                  //PS3USB PS3(&Usb,0x00,0x15,0x83,0x3D,0x0A,0x57); // This will also store the bluetooth address - this can be obtained from the dongle when running the sketch

bool printAngle;
uint8_t state = 0;

int motora1 = 4;
int motora2 = 7;
int motoraspeed = 6;
int motorb1 = 3;
int motorb2 = 2;
int motorbspeed = 5;


void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);
#if !defined(__MIPSEL__)
    while (!Serial); // Wait for serial port to connect - used on Leonardo, Teensy and other boards with built-in USB CDC serial connection
#endif
    if (Usb.Init() == -1) {
        Serial.print(F("\r\nOSC did not start"));
        while (1); //halt
    }
    Serial.print(F("\r\nPS3 USB Library Started"));
    pinMode(motora1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motora2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motoraspeed, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motorb1, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motorb2, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(motorbspeed, OUTPUT);
    delay(5000);
}

void loop() {
    Usb.Task();

    if (PS3.PS3Connected || PS3.PS3NavigationConnected) {

        if (PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY) == 0) { //go forward
            Serial.print(F("\r\nLeftHatY: "));
            Serial.print(PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY));
            digitalWrite(motora1, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(motora2, LOW);
            digitalWrite(motoraspeed, 255);
            digitalWrite(motorb1, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(motorb2, LOW);
            digitalWrite(motorbspeed, 255);
        } else if (PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY) == 255) { //go backward
            Serial.print(F("\r\nLeftHatY: "));
            Serial.print(PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY));
            digitalWrite(motora1, LOW);
            digitalWrite(motora2, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(motoraspeed, 255);
            digitalWrite(motorb1, LOW);
            digitalWrite(motorb2, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(motorbspeed, 255);
        } else if PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatX) == 0) { //turn left
            Serial.print(F("\r\RightHatX: "));
            Serial.print(PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatX));
            digitalWrite(motora1, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(motora2, LOW);
            digitalWrite(motoraspeed, 200);
            digitalWrite(motorb1, LOW);
            digitalWrite(motorb2, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(motorbspeed, 200);
        } else if (PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatX) == 255) { //turn right
            Serial.print(F("\r\RightHatX: "));
            Serial.print(PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatX));
            digitalWrite(motora1, LOW);
            digitalWrite(motora2, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(motoraspeed, 200);
            digitalWrite(motorb1, HIGH);
            digitalWrite(motorb2, LOW);
            digitalWrite(motorbspeed, 200);
        } else { //stop moving
            Serial.print(F("\r\RightHatX: "));
            Serial.print(PS3.getAnalogHat(RightHatX));
            Serial.print(F("\r\nLeftHatY: "));
            Serial.print(PS3.getAnalogHat(LeftHatY));
            digitalWrite(motora1, LOW);
            digitalWrite(motora2, LOW);
            digitalWrite(motoraspeed, 0);
            digitalWrite(motorb1, LOW);
            digitalWrite(motorb2, LOW);
            digitalWrite(motorbspeed, 0);
        }
    }
}
```